# Within a Query can you have a result changed to something based on a returned value

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL Developer Version 18.2.0.183, Build 183.1748

This request for help comes from a lack of knowledge on the subject. I have a query I am working on and one of the fields in the Query will always return a Value of either "S" or "C". Anytime a "S" is returned I need that field to instead of outputting a "S" to instead output "Residential" and anytime a "C" is returned to instead output "Commercial".

Here is a Sample of the query:

```
    SELECT
    DBSTAGE.OAWOM.WORKORDERNUMBER "Work Order Number", 
    DBSTAGE.OAWOM.BILLTYPECODE "Bill Type Code", 
    DBSTAGE.OAWOD.SERVICECODE "Line Description"
    FROM
    DBSTAGE.OAWOM, 
    DBSTAGE.AOWOD
    WHERE
    DBSTAGE.OAWOM.WORKORDERNUMBER = DBSTAGE.OAWOD.WORKORDERNUMBER 
    AND DBSTAGE.OAWOM.SITEID = DBSTAGE.OAWOD.SITEID
```

This query outputs the following:
["ACTUAL OUTPUT"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXOXG.png)

And I am wanting it to instead output this:
["DESIRED OUTPUT"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z89NK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CASE statement in your select to change the field output based on field input value.

Eg

```
SELECT cust_last_name,
   CASE credit_limit WHEN 100 THEN 'Low'
   WHEN 5000 THEN 'High'
   ELSE 'Medium' END
   FROM customers;
```

Comment: There are other select statements before and after this one, can the CASE be used in the middle of a Select statement?

Comment: Yes it can be used at anywhere. You can try and read oracle documentation on CASE construct